# css filter in google map without the map marker

Tags: javascript, css, google-maps, google-maps-markers

I have used CSS filter for the MAP. Now it is work well. But I want to show the original map marker, I mean the filter effect don't need to the map marker.
The image is what I want
[image].

Right now it looks like as in this [link](http://newgenerationweb.com/dev/test/jopesa/).

Comment: Would setting the z-index of the marker higher than that of the overlay help?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Questions seeking code help must include the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself**.   Although you have provided a link to an example, if the link were to become invalid, your question would be of no value to other future SO users with the same problem.

Comment: Take a look at : https://developers.google.com/maps/tutorials/customizing/custom-markers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want maps in grayscale and red marker, you have to use style array.
Here the explanations: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/styling

Here a repository of different styles for Google Maps: https://snazzymaps.com/